# Xamarin.Forms: how to center an Image in TitleView when ToolbarItems are displayed?

Tags: custom-renderer, titleview, xamarin.forms.shell, toolbaritems

I'm working on a **Xamarin.Forms.Shell app** containing **4 tabs**. I would like to display a **common** `Title` containing a **centered SVG logo** on all these pages.

For this, I can use a `TitleView` like this:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage Source="resource://ShellAppSample.Resources.logoTitle.svg"
                                      DownsampleHeight="6"
                                      HeightRequest="45"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

This works and the logo is well centered in the `NavigationBar`. However, if the page contains `ToolbarItems`, the logo is no longer centered.

For example, on a page I've a `ToolBarItem` like this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Refresh"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Priority="0"
                 Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                 CommandParameter="{x:Reference webView}">                             
        <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconRefresh}"
                             FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                             Size="Medium"/>
        </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Is there another way to display a **centered Image from a SVG as Title**, by using `CustomRenderer` or calculating the size of the `ToolbarItems`?

I've seen that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613454/xamarin-forms-shell-titleview-does-not-center-image) has already been posted 1 year ago, but without any solution...

I've already tried to redraw the `ToolbarItem` in the `TitleView` like this:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage Source="resource://ShellAppSample.Resources.blackLogoTitle.svg"
                                          DownsampleHeight="6"
                                          HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                          HeightRequest="45"
                                          BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
        <Image HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconRefresh}"
                                 FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                                 Size="Medium"/>
            </Image.Source>
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference webView}"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

On iOS it's correct, but I can see that:

- the logo is **not exactly centered** like on the pages that don't contain any `ToolBarItem`, as there is a small gap when I switch between the pages
- the icon is **not positioned** like when I use a `ToolBarItem`

On Android, the result it's not correct: the logo hasn't the same height, and the icon is out of the `TitleView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've managed my `TitleView`s like this:

For the `Image`:

```
<Shell.TitleView >
    <Image Source="resource://ShellAppSample.Resources.logo.jpg"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Margin="{OnPlatform Android='0,0,16,0', Default=0}"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

For the `Label`:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Margin="{OnPlatform Android='0,0,16,0', Default=0}"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

And for  `Label` with one "medium" size `ToolBarItem`:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" /> 
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
               Grid.Column="1"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="{OnPlatform Android='0,0,16,0', Default=0}"/>
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Refresh"
                 Order="Primary"
                 Priority="1"
                 Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">                             
        <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FalIconRefresh}"
                             FontFamily="FontAwesomeLight"
                             Size="Medium"/>
        </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

I've checked the alignment through the [DebugRainbows](https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.DebugRainbows) package and it looked fine on iOS/Android, on small/large devices.

It's not perfect, and I need to update rules if I add other `ToolBarItem`s but it worked like this.