# Centering NavigationPage.TitleView in WinUI

Tags: maui, winui, titleview

Running my `ContentPage` in WinUI, which is wrapped with a `NavigationPage` at runtime, needs a custom `TitleView`

I've put the same content in both TitleView and Content sections:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">
        <Label Text="Center me!" Style="{StaticResource H1}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">
        <Label Text="Center me!" Style="{StaticResource H1}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The title won't center like the `ContentPage.Content` or [like Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613454/xamarin-forms-shell-titleview-does-not-center-image) does. No matter what I've tried, `<Grid>`, `<HoritonalStackLayout>` and every `HorizontalOptions` the content is always pinned on left and sized exactly fit the text, instead of expanding the `<Grid>` or `<StackLayout`> to the window width (WinUI) and centering its children.

The only thing it seems to respond to is `WidthRequest` but that isn't very useful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your description, this is a known issue that being tracked in the link below, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10703

Normally, when setting `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` of `<Grid>` or `<HoritonalStackLayout>` in `WinUI Maui`, the `TitleView` content should have **expanded across the entire width of the window width**.

Unfortunately, it failed to work as expected in `WinUI Maui`. And I also tested in other platforms in Maui, the `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` can function well in `TitleView` content.